# How to save generated barcode into folder as an img?

Tags: php

I'm a beginner. I'm trying to generate barcode and save into a folder 'uploads' as an image.
Here is my code, but it doesn't work. What is the problem? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
    // Including all required classes
    require_once('class/BCGFontFile.php');
    require_once('class/BCGColor.php');
    require_once('class/BCGDrawing.php');

    // Including the barcode technology
    require_once('class/BCGcode128.barcode.php');

    $font = new BCGFontFile('./font/Arial.ttf', 18);

    // The arguments are R, G, B for color.
    $color_black = new BCGColor(0, 0, 0);
    $color_white = new BCGColor(255, 255, 255);


        $code = new BCGcode128();
        $code->setScale(2); // Resolution
        $code->setThickness(30); // Thickness
        $code->setForegroundColor($color_black); // Color of bars
        $code->setBackgroundColor($color_white); // Color of spaces
        $code->setFont($font); // Font (or 0)
        $code->parse('hi'); // Text


    $drawing = new BCGDrawing('../uploads/',$color_white);
    $drawing->setBarcode($code);
    $drawing->draw();


    // Draw (or save) the image into PNG format.
    $drawing->finish(BCGDrawing::IMG_FORMAT_PNG);
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Make sure to have error reporting turned on and are displaying errors during development

Comment: it doesnt give any error. when i leave first parameter empty it displays barcode.                                              $drawing = new CGDrawing('',$color_white);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the proper filename. Like this:

```
$drawing = new BCGDrawing('../uploads/filename.png', $color_white);
```

or this:

```
$drawing->setFilename('../uploads/filename.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

You `uploads` folder should be writtable by the webserver. Also the documentation states you need a filename

construct">http://www.barcodephp.com/en/manual/drawing#_construct

Think about using `setFilename()`

Answer (score 0):

When you have take a look into the [manual for ->finish()](http://www.barcodephp.com/en/manual/drawing#finish) you find this

```
 Writes the image in the specified file. The file has been specified when you constructed the class, if you didn't, the image will be displayed.
```

Your solution can be find under http://www.barcodephp.com/en/manual/drawing#__construct